# How gas fee to Mint an NFT are really calculated on Ethereum

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I came across an NFT project listing their NFTs with 25.000 $ each. when I click on the button mint even though, I'll not buy it because I can' afford it. Metamask pops up with $28,827.05 Total including gas fees.
How are The gas fees calculated in this case? is it based on the price of the NFT + the network fees?
Can please anyone give an explanation for that?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what appears if your transaction is expected to fail.

Metamask simulates each transaction before you can send it in order to estimate the gas it will use. If the transaction would revert (and thus fail), it sets the gas limit to some very high amount (around 2M gas). You would not actually pay this much for gas fees, even if you sent it like this.

You can see this if you click on the "edit" button in the gas fees screen.

Comment: How much do you think will I pay in terms of gas fees, if I have that amount of ETH to mint that NFT. there is any website/tool that helps to stimulate gas fees?

Comment: Well in that specific case, as Vector said, it looks like the transaction is going to revert. It's definitely not a general rule, but usually when a transaction reverts it uses very little gas because all the checks (the points where the code verifies that everything is alright, and reverts if it isnt) are usually done before actually starting to execute anything.